# remove files and prompt directories only

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rm

As I was deleting many obsolete file trees on a Linux machine I was wondering if there is an easy way to remove files recursively while prompting only on directories.

I could use `rm -ri` but there some much files that it would be really annoying to answer for every one of them. What really matter to me is being prompted on folders to have more control on what happens.

I am not a bash expert so I am asking if there is a simple way to do this.

Here is my attempt with a long bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

promptRemoveDir()
{
  fileCount=$(ls -1 $1 | wc -l)
  prompt=1
  while [ $prompt == 1 ]
  do
    read -p "remove directory: $1($fileCount files) ? [yl]: " answer
      case $answer in
        [yY])
          rm -r $1
          prompt=0
          ;;
        l)
          echo $(ls -A $1)
          ;;
        *)
          prompt=0
          ;;
      esac
  done
}

removeDir()
{
  if [ "$(ls -A $1)" ]
  then dirs=$(find $1/* -maxdepth 0 -type d)
  fi

  if [[ -z $dirs ]]
  then
    promptRemoveDir $1
  else
    for dir in $dirs
    do
      removeDir $dir
    done
    promptRemoveDir $1
  fi
}

for i in $*
do
  if [ -d $i ]
  then
    removeDir $i
  else
    rm $i
  fi
done
```

Comment: What do you mean, prompted before deleting all files in a directory ?

Comment: Why did you use `rm -ri`? `-i` option prompts before every removal. Can't you use `rm -r`?

Comment: @Jidder I mean, asking confirmation before deleting a directory and its files. however if a directory contains already one directory or more, the sub-directories need to be checked first to not miss any one of them. Check the recursive removeDir function to help understand.

Comment: @SanketParmar I used -ri to remove recursively in a file tree. I could not use -i only because this would require to enter in each directory manually starting by the deepest directories in the file tree. The previous script automate this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just came upon the -depth option of the find command that is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe I just missed that:

> -depth Process each directory's contents before the directory itself.  The -delete action also implies -depth.

So similar to @Jidder's code, I can write this:

```
dirs=$(find ./test_script -depth -type d); for i in $dirs; do read -p "Delete files in $i?  " REPLY; if [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]]; then rm -r $i; fi; done;
```

And for more readability:

```
dirs=$(find ./test_script -depth -type d)

for i in $dirs 
do 
    read -p "Delete files in $i? " REPLY
    if [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]]
    then rm -r $i
    fi
done;
```

Comment: This wont be recursive though ? It will only process the directories directly underneath `./test_script` and you will not know if these contain directories further down. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: The default behavior of find command is to search in the whole searched directory tree. So yes in this case it gives me all the directories under the "./test_script" directory. the -depth option sort the results from the deepest directories to the shallowest.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question properly this should work

```
Dirs=$(find . -type d)
```

Removes just the files in the directories specified

```
for i in "$Dirs"; do read -p "Delete files in "$i": ";if [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]]; then find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -0 rm  ; fi ;done
```

If you want to delete the folders as well, this will read from lowest directory(none below it) upwards.

```
for i in $(echo "$Dirs" | sed '1!G;h;$!d' ); do read -p "Delete files in $i: ";if [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]]; then rm -r "$i"; fi ;done
```

Comment: fails if directory names contain spaces. quote "$Dirs" after for, and $i after rm.

Comment: This way you would delete some directories inside directories before asking for confirmation

Comment: @dletozeun Only deletes files

Comment: @Jidder I see but I want to delete files and directories. However your edit with the second code snippet works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version from me. There's no need to use `ls` and `find`.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob

function remove_dir_i {
    local DIR=$1  ## Optional. We can just use $1.
    local SUBFILES=("$DIR"/*) FILE
    for (( ;; )); do
        read -p "Remove directory: $DIR (${#SUBFILES[@]} files)? [YNLQ]: "
        case "$REPLY" in
        [yY])
            echo rm -fr "$DIR"
            return 0
            ;;
        [nN])
            for FILE in "${SUBFILES[@]}"; do
                if [[ -d $FILE ]]; then
                    remove_dir_i "$FILE" || return 1
                # else
                #   ## Apparently we skip deleting a file. If we do this
                #   ## we could actually simplify the function further
                #   ## since we also delete the file at first loop.
                #   # echo "Removing file \"$FILE.\""
                #   # rm -f "$FILE"
                fi
            done
            return 0
            ;;
        [lL])
            printf '%s\n' "${SUBFILES[@]}"
            ;;
        [qQ])
            return 1
            ;;
        # *)
        #   echo "Please answer Y(es), N(o), L(ist) or Q(uit)."
        #   ;;
        esac
    done
}

for FILE; do
    if [[ -d $FILE ]]; then
        remove_dir_i "$FILE"
    else
        # echo "Removing file \"$FILE.\""
        echo rm -f "$FILE"
    fi
done
```

Remove `echo` from `rm` commands when you're sure it's working already. Test:

```
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/ABOUT-NLS
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/acinclude.m4
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/aclocal.m4
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/AUTHORS
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/build-aux (12 files)? [YNLQ]: n
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/build-aux/snippet (5 files)? [YNLQ]: n
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/ChangeLog
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/ChangeLog.1
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/config.h.in
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/configure
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/configure.ac
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/COPYING
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/doc (25 files)? [YNLQ]: n
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/gnu (358 files)? [YNLQ]: n
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/gnu/uniwidth (2 files)? [YNLQ]: n
rm -f /tmp/tar-1.27.1/INSTALL
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/lib (19 files)? [YNLQ]: 
...
```

Comment: Thanks but I think there is still the problem I was pointing out in other answers. From your output :

Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/build-aux then :
Remove directory: /tmp/tar-1.27.1/build-aux/snippet [YNLQ]:

If the build-aux directory is removed then the build-aux/snippet would not exist anymore and and it is too late for removal confirmation.

Comment: You actually delete files in first loop. How about other files found during recursion - do you plan to delete them as well? If subdirectories were chosen to be not deleted, would you still be asked if the parent directory would be deleted, or by default you'd not touch them?

Comment: Some minor modifications from my could would probably fix it already.